# ruby on rails gem update giving error aftering fetching rack-2.0.1.gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to do a `gem update` in my terminal, but getting an error:

```
Updating installed gems
Updating actionpack
Fetching: activesupport-5.0.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activesupport-5.0.0
Fetching: rack-2.0.1.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/wrappers/rackup
```

Can someone help why i'm getting this?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is wondering, I guess I just needed to give permission, and in order to do that just add `sudo` command in the front, ie:

```
$ sudo gem update
```

Comment: That's exactly what `Errno::EACCES` and `Permission denied` were telling you.